# Set Up IIs 7.5 with anonymous authentication for Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, web-config, iis-7.5

Triying to login to Active Directory (asp.net webforms website) with IIS anonymous Authentication.

Got this error:

> {System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList} 'entry.Guid' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.Name' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.NativeGuid' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.NativeObject' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.ObjectSecurity' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.Options' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.Parent' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' {System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection} 'entry.SchemaClassName' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 'entry.SchemaEntry' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Ideas?

[image: Element receiving error]
[image: Atributes with error]

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Anonymous authentication has nothing to do with the `web.config` fragment you pasted (as that's for authorization). `IUSR_machinename` is already obsolete, and you should never see it again. Also reformat the question as images are not enough, http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: I just want a way to LOGIN to my website (asp.net webforms based) with anonymous authentication using Active Directory

Comment: Learn the keywords "forms authentication against Active Directory" and then you can find tons of posts via search engines, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/316748/how-to-authenticate-against-the-active-directory-by-using-forms-authen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forms Authentication Using Active Directory / LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002807/forms-authentication-using-active-directory-ldap)

Comment: You cannot "login with anonymous authentication". Anonymous authentication means that no login happens and you have no way to know who is viewing the website. So which do you want? Do you want the user to login so you know who they are? Or do you want anonymous authentication?